# ng-template for complex labels in md-tab material2

Tags: angular, angular-material2, ng-template

I am using [material2 md-tab](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview). As per the documentation if I want to give the more complex label to tab headers then I need to use `ng-template` with `md-tab-label`. I just want to know the strategy why they have chosen the `ng-template` way? Isn't there should be

```
<md-tab-label>complex label</md-tab-label>
```

like this as other material components like `md-card` have defined the `<md-card-title>` and `<md-card-subtitle>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `md-menu` instead of `md-tab`. Because tab bar is not used for that purpose:

`app.component.ts`:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'menu-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'menu-overview-example.html',
})
export class MenuOverviewExample {}
```

```html
<button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
  <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</md-menu>
```

Comment: Please don't use code snippets and use just syntax highlighting instead.